# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running into a `NoSuchMethodError` when I am using SparkRDD API to read data from Kafka. The stack trace looks like this when there is the very first record available and there is an exception as follow:

```
23/12/10 16:41:54 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 1.1.0
23/12/10 16:41:54 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07
23/12/10 16:41:54 INFO InternalKafkaConsumer: Initial fetch for spark-executor-recommender recommender-0 14
23/12/10 16:41:54 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 246.0 (TID 249)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lorg/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer.get$(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$CachedKafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:225)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1933)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$count$1(RDD.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(RDD.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
23/12/10 16:41:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 246.0 (TID 249) (higbattleship executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lorg/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer.get$(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$CachedKafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:225)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1933)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$count$1(RDD.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(RDD.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

my code is as follow:

```scala
/**
 * 模块作用:实时推荐算法
 * 启动服务:mongodb kafka-zookeeper redis
 */

/**
 * MongoDB:
 * StreamRecs
 * Rating
 * MovieRecs
 */

package com.zyx.streaming
import org.junit.Test
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.{MongoClient, MongoClientURI}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils, LocationStrategies}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._


// 连接助手对象
object ConnHelper extends Serializable{
  // 连接Redis集群
  lazy val jedis = new Jedis("192.168.234.200")
  // 连接MongoDB服务
  lazy val mongoClient =
    MongoClient(MongoClientURI("mongodb://192.168.234.200:28017/recommender"))
}

case class MongoConfig(uri:String,db:String)
// 定义标准推荐对象
case class Recommendation(mid:Int, score:Double)
// 定义基于预测评分d1用户的推荐
case class StreamRecs(uid:Int, recs:Seq[Recommendation])
// 定义基于LFMd电影特征向量的电影的相似度列表
case class MovieRecs(mid: Int, recs: Seq[Recommendation])


object StreamingRecommender {
  val MAX_USER_RATINGS_NUM = 20
  val MAX_SIM_MOVIES_NUM = 20
  val MONGODB_STREAM_RECS_COLLECTION = "StreamRecs"
  val MONGODB_RATING_COLLECTION = "Rating"
  val MONGODB_MOVIE_RECS_COLLECTION = "MovieRecs"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /**
     * 设置配置信息
     */
    val config = Map(
      "spark.cores" -> "local[*]",
      "mongo.uri" -> "mongodb://192.168.234.200:28017/recommender",
      "mongo.db" -> "recommender",
      "kafka.topic" -> "recommender"
    )

    /**
     * 创建spark配置
     */
    // 创建sparkConf配置
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(config("spark.cores")).setAppName("StreamingRecommender")
    // 创建sparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

    import spark.implicits._

    /**
     * 广播电影相似度矩阵
     */

    implicit var mongoConfig = MongoConfig(config("mongo.uri"), config("mongo.db"))

    val simMoviesMatrix = spark
      .read
      .option("uri", mongoConfig.uri)
      .option("collection", MONGODB_MOVIE_RECS_COLLECTION)
      .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql")
      .load()
      //.select("mid", "recs")
      .as[MovieRecs]
      .rdd
      .map {
        recs => (recs.mid, recs.recs.map(x => (x.mid, x.score)).toMap)
      }.collectAsMap()

    // 加载电影相似度矩阵 进行广播
    val simMoviesMatrixBroadcast = sc.broadcast(simMoviesMatrix)

     /**
     * 创建kafka的连接配置
     */
    val kafkaPara = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "192.168.234.200:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "recommender",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest"
    )

    // 创建kafka连接
    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](Array(config("kafka.topic")), kafkaPara))

    // 格式:UID|MID|SCORE|TIMESTAMP|
    val ratingStream = kafkaStream.map {
      case msg =>
        var attr = msg.value().split("\\|")
        (attr(0).toInt, attr(1).toInt, attr(2).toDouble, attr(3).split("#")(0).toInt)
    }

    ratingStream.foreachRDD {
      rdd =>
        rdd.map {
          case (uid, mid, score, timestame) =>
            println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
            // 从redis中获取用户最近M次电影评分
            val userRecentlyRatings = getUserRecentlyRating(MAX_USER_RATINGS_NUM, uid, ConnHelper.jedis)
            //
            // 从获取流中获取电影P最相似的K个电影
            val simMovies = getTopSimMovies(MAX_SIM_MOVIES_NUM, mid, uid, simMoviesMatrixBroadcast.value)
            //
            // 计算候选电影的推荐优先级
            val streamRecs = computeMovieScores(simMoviesMatrixBroadcast.value, userRecentlyRatings, simMovies)
            //
            // 将数据保存到MongoDB
            saveRecsToMongoDB(uid, streamRecs)
        }.count()
    }

    /**
     * 启动Streaming程序
     */
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }


  /**
   * 获取用户最近M次电影评分
   *
   * @param num   评分个数
   * @param uid   用户
   * @param jedis redis端口
   * @return
   */
  def getUserRecentlyRating(num: Int, uid: Int, jedis: Jedis): Array[(Int, Double)] = {
    // 从用户队列中获取num个评分
    jedis.lrange("uid:" + uid.toString, 0, num - 1).map {
      item =>
        val attr = item.split("\\:")
        (attr(0).trim.toInt, attr(1).trim.toDouble)
    }.toArray
  }

  /**
   * 获取电影P最相似的K个电影
   *
   * @param num        相似电影数量
   * @param mid        电影ID
   * @param uid        用户ID
   * @param simMovies  电影相似度广播矩阵
   * @param mongConfig MongoDB配置
   * @return
   */
  def getTopSimMovies(num: Int, mid: Int, uid: Int,
                      simMovies: scala.collection.Map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, Double]])
                     (implicit mongConfig: MongoConfig): Array[Int] = {

    // 从广播变量的电影相似度矩阵获取当前电影最相似的电影
    val allSimMovies = simMovies.get(mid).get.toArray
    // 先获取用户已经观看过的电影
    val ratingExist = ConnHelper.mongoClient(mongConfig.db)(MONGODB_RATING_COLLECTION)
      .find(MongoDBObject("uid" -> uid)).toArray.map {
        item => item.get("mid").toString.toInt
      }
    // 过滤用户观看过的电影并进行排序
    allSimMovies.filter(x => !ratingExist.contains(x._1)).sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
      .take(num).map(x => x._1)
  }

  /**
   * 计算候选电影的推荐分数
   *
   * @param simMovies           电影相似度矩阵
   * @param userRecentlyRatings 电影最近的k次评分
   * @param topSimMovies        当前电影的最相似的k个电影
   * @return
   */
  def computeMovieScores(simMovies: scala.collection.Map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, Double]],
                         userRecentlyRatings: Array[(Int, Double)], topSimMovies: Array[Int]): Array[(Int, Double)] = {

    // 用于保存最后的每一个待选电影和他的评分
    val score = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[(Int, Double)]()

    // 用于保存每一个电影的增强因子
    val increMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]()

    // 用于保存每一个电影的衰减因子
    val decreMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]()

    for (topSimMovie <- topSimMovies; userRecentlyRating <- userRecentlyRatings) {
      val simScore = getMoviesSimScore(simMovies, userRecentlyRating._1, topSimMovie)

      if (simScore > 0.6) {
        score += ((topSimMovie, simScore * userRecentlyRating._2))
        if (userRecentlyRating._2 > 3) {
          increMap(topSimMovie) = increMap.getOrDefault(topSimMovie, 0) + 1
        } else {
          decreMap(topSimMovie) = decreMap.getOrDefault(topSimMovie, 0) + 1
        }
      }

    }

    score.groupBy(_._1).map {
      case (mid, sims) =>
        (mid, sims.map(_._2).sum / sims.length +
          math.log10(increMap.getOrDefault(mid, 1)) - math.log10(decreMap.getOrDefault(mid, 1)))

    }.toArray.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)


  }

  /**
   * 用于找出用户评分的电影和候选电影的相似度
   *
   * @param simMovies       相似度矩阵
   * @param userRatingMovie 用户评分的电影
   * @param topSimMovie     候选电影
   * @return
   */
  def getMoviesSimScore(simMovies: scala.collection.Map[Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, Double]],
                        userRatingMovie: Int, topSimMovie: Int): Double = {
    simMovies.get(topSimMovie) match {
      case Some(sim) => sim.get(userRatingMovie) match {
        case Some(score) => score
        case None => 0.0
      }
      case None => 0.0
    }
  }

  /**
   * 数据保存MongoDB
   *
   * @param uid
   * @param streamRecs 流式推荐
   * @param mongConfig MongoDB配置
   */
  def saveRecsToMongoDB(uid: Int, streamRecs: Array[(Int, Double)])
                       (implicit mongConfig: MongoConfig): Unit = {
    val streaRecsCollection = ConnHelper.mongoClient(mongConfig.db)(MONGODB_STREAM_RECS_COLLECTION)

    streaRecsCollection.findAndRemove(MongoDBObject("uid" -> uid))
    streaRecsCollection.insert(MongoDBObject("uid" -> uid, "recs" ->
      streamRecs.map(x => MongoDBObject("mid" -> x._1, "score" -> x._2))))
  }

}
```

my Spark version: 3.3.1;
my Kafka version: 1.1.0;

Please help me to find out what's wrong!

Comment: By the way, I am not a native English speaker, and this is my first time to ask a question in a English platform, so I may not be familiar with some English expression, please don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark Streaming Kafka library is deprecated, but the error is saying you're missing kafka-clients.jar, which you must include in `--packages` option during `spark-submit`

If you use Structured Streaming, you'd use `kafka-sql-kafka-0-10`, instead